# Watermark image on Autodesk 3D models

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a platform where I am showing a 3D models mapped with 2D models. 
I want to know if there is any way to add watermark on 3D model, either in viewer API or while designing these models. I think my designer are using Maya, but any Autodesk tool will work.

One way I know that to put watermark images on corners or in between using CSS an JS, but that will loose user interactivity with model.

Can you suggest some better option or point me to some useful article.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the use of CSS and JS watermark is useful, as it is easy to be overridden/removed.

Since your model is coming from Maya, the easiest way of adding a watermark to a model, is to add a texture with a watermark to it.
In this way, after the model is translated and displayed in [Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/developers_guide/overview/), it will keep having this texture with watermark applied to it.